# how can content between a class put in a variable after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

How do I retrieve the content between and including the following `<div class="adding">` and store it in a variable?

```
<div class="adding">
    <b>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="mediumCell">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="توضیح" title="نام پکیج تور خارجی">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column" style="margin: 5px 3px;">
            <div class="mediumCell">
                <div class="adda">
                    <a href="#" class="add_input"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </b>
</div>
```

```
var adding = '<div class="adding"><b><div class="column"><div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="توضیح" title="نام پکیج تور خارجی"></div></div><div class="column" style="margin: 5px 3px;"><div class="mediumCell"><div class="adda"><a href="#" class="add_input"></a></div></div></div></b></div>'
```

In each click I want to get the content just once.

Unfortunately, after two or more clicks getting content several times together (E.x: after two clicks it stores the content twice).

I tried this:

```
$(function () {        
    var i = $('.adding').size();
    $('.add_input').live('click', function () {
        var scntDiv = '.' + $(this)
                           .closest('.find_input')
                           .find('div')
                           .attr('class');
            var input = $(scntDiv).html();
            $(this).remove();
            $(input).appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method, as others have said, but there's a catch: that method returns the *inner* HTML content of the element, so the markup of the outer `<div>` element won't be included in the result.

Since you seem to want that markup, you can work around the issue with [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
var adding = $("div.adding").clone().wrap("<div>").parent().html();
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: If you're going to use this very often, it's a piece of cake to wrap it in a plugin.

Comment: @Tomas: I mean it's a lot of work to clone a bunch of elements just to get the outer markup...

Comment: ...as someone has already done (but with a slightly different solution) :P http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/ (linked to in the post that Cybernate linked to in his comment on the question)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the *inner* HTML using the `html` function:

```
var adding = $(".adding").html():
```

...which will give you the browser's version of the markup within the first matching `div` (the first `div` with the class "adding"). It's fairly simple at that point to wrap it with the markup for the div, unless there are a lot of chaotic attributes involved.

**However**, note that the markup you get back may not be what you expect, because your HTML is invalid. `b` elements cannot contain `div` elements ([`b` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) may only contain [*phrasing content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#phrasing-content); [`div` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) are [*flow content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content)), and so the browser adjust things as it sees fit to display something reasonable. This is a Bad Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>, it's much better with dynamic web apps to ensure that your HTML is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're asking for ?

```
var adding;
$('.adding').click(function(){
    adding = $(this).html();
    alert(adding);
});
```

Comment: He wants the *outer* HTML, not the inner. I made the same mistake at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
var adding = $(".adding").html();
```

maybe?